# Update using SELECT Query MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a query that have INSERT with SELECT :-

```
    INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition;
```

What I need to do is insert custom value for column with the select like this :

```
    INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT column1, column3
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition
    column2 = "DATA";
```

The column 2 I don't need it to get it from the another table I wont to insert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a literal value:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, 'DATA', column3
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

I didn't include any actual Java code, but the change you would need should be straightforward.  You can either include the literal in your select, or bind a constant string value to a prepared statement.

Comment: I modified it and put it in java and it did well ! Thanks for the help, I will give you the best answer in a few minutes